# How to add text on Isotope Image?

Tags: jquery, css, blogs

I've build a sort of portfolio using Isotope and Jquery but I don't know how to put text on my pictures without destroying all the isotope portfolio.

I've tried a lot of thing : using position:relative for the pictures and position:absolute for the text but it doesn't work. What should I do ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this problem and it happened to me. You can use *HTML5* Tag which is **figcaption**. After using **figcaption** tag you can figure it via CSS.

```
<figcaption>example</figcaption>
```